# Wordpress how to server all static files under wp-includes from a subdomain?

Tags: wordpress

how to server all static files under wp-includes from a sub domain ? Right now if the site is `www.example.com` then the static files are from `www.example.com/wp-includes/...`  Want it from `static.example.com/wp-includes/...`  I guess its an update from wp-options table ? Any experience ?

Comment: Depending on your web server software you can reverse proxy or rewrite requests from www.example.com/wp-includes/ to static.example.com/wp-includes/. On IIS, an Outbound Rule is such an option, see https://www.saotn.org/create-cdn-using-iis-outbound-rules/ for example. This basically rewrites the output stream, changing `www` to `static`, before the receiver gets the HTML in his/her browser

Comment: is there away to fix a php file or update its db so that those static files will be served from a sub so I can cdn it ? Understanding I can rewrite by the webserver software but would use it as the last resort as its a tag slower

Comment: not that I know of, because WordPress uses `site_url()` to retrieve the site url for the current site: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url.

Comment: @TommyLord No you cannot move the wp-includes folder, it is hard coded throughout Wordpress core.

Comment: I totally forgot that WP-Super-Cache has this offload option in their CDN implementation, maybe that's good enough for you @TommyLord? The physical location remains the same, but you can serve `/wp-includes/` from a sub domain

Comment: lol you did it. How to award you  now ?

Answer (score 0):

I did the same implementation to serve all the static contents (css, js, images) for all the folders (wp-includes, wp-contents and wp-admin) to be from the sub domain using the IIS redirect rule.

If you are using IIS as a web server then follow the simple directives from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324000